# Going over a vector (Segmentation fault)

Tags: c++, vector, std, fault

I supose there is a problem with the iterators, but I can't understand why!
Could you please give me some more info?

I have the movie class with the following:

```
public:
    vector<string> casting() const;

private:
    string _titol;
    short _year;
    vector<string> _alies;
    string _director;
    vector<string> _casting;
```

The `casting()` method just  returns the _casting vector

I have my main.cpp where I call:

```
void Movies::actorMovies(string actor){
bool existeix = false;
std::map<titleyear,Movie>::iterator it = _pelis.begin();
std::vector<string>::iterator it2;

for(it; it!=_pelis.end(); it++){
    for(it2=it->second.casting().begin(); it2!=it->second.casting().end(); it2++){
        /*if((*it2).compare(actor)==0){
            cout<<"Titol: "<<it->first.t<<endl<<"Any: "<<it->first.y<<endl;
            existeix = true;
        }*/
    }


}
if(!existeix) 
    cout<<"NOT FOUND"<<endl;
}
```

The Segmentation fault comes when i want Uncomment the if statement.
Can someone see what's happenning here?

Comment: actually it's not a main.cpp, it's a Movies.cpp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your premise is wrong. The `casting()` method returns *a new copy* of the `_casting` vector every time it is called. Thus `it2` can never equal `it->second.casting().end()`, since it's an iterator to a completely different container!

In fact, `it2` is immediately invalidated at the end of the full expression, since it's an iterator into a temporary container that dies immediately.

If `casting()` is meant to provide a view of the actual `_casting` vector, it should return an lvalue:

```
const std::vector<std::string> & casting() const { return _casting; }
//                            ^^^
```

Comment: oh! it makes all sense...
But I can't understand why it's a copy: here it is:
`vector<string> Movie::casting() const
{
    return _casting;
}`

Comment: @d2Bamp: When a function returns a prvalue, the return value is a new, temporary object initialized from the operand of the `return` statement. This is analogous to how `a` is initialized from `n` in `int a = n;` vs `int & a = n;`: The initializer is the same, but in the expression `(a)` denotes a different object in each case. In the first case, it's a new object, in the second, it's the same object as `n`.

Answer (score 3):

The `casting()` function returns a temporary vector *by value*.  Different calls to the function each return a new copy of the vector.

So when you write:

```
for(it2=it->second.casting().begin();
```

the `it2` is immediately dangling because the temporary vector now gets destroyed.

The test `it2!=it->second.casting().end();` compares a dangling iterator with the end of a new copy of `_casting`, causing undefined behaviour.

There are two options to fix this:

1. Store the result: `vector<string> casting = it->second.casting(); for (it2 = casting.begin(); ..........`
2. Make `casting()` return by reference, so that you will work on the actual instance of the vector inside `it->second`.